# Function names with symbol characters makes Googling difficult

Tags: haskell, symbols

In Haskell, many function names contain only symbol characters. Like `$$`, `>>=`, `>>`, `:`, `->`, `=>`, `=~`.

Since I am new to Haskell, I am finding it difficult to search their meanings in Google. For example, to understand what `->` means in Haskell, I need to use the search string `hyphen followed by greater than` which is not the best approach, as per me.

Is there a place that I could search for functions with symbols only?

Comment: Answer from Radio Erewan: In principle yes, but -> is not a function ... it's a type constructor.

Comment: You can use [hoogle](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle) to search for Haskell functions, and it works well for operators.  However, the `->` won't come up because it's part of Haskell syntax, not an operator (as is `=>`).

Comment: use [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=(-%3E)) or [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=-%3E) but not that these are called operators

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, this is a known bug with Google. You might consider a better search engine like [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/).

In general you need to look up the documentation for the actual function. To do this, you need to know what *module* it's defined in. The easiest way to determine this is to load up your source file in GHCi (so that you have all of its imports etc.) and then ask for the operator's `:info` thusly:

```
Prelude> :info (>>=)
class Monad (m :: * -> *) where
  (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
  ...
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
infixl 1 >>=
Prelude>
```

If the type signature is not enough, then this also tells you that you need to google the `GHC.Base` module, and the `Monad` typeclass.  By itself that's pretty googleable, but if that typeclass keyword weren't there, what you would do is to google `GHC.Base`, the first result leading to [the `base` package overview page](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base). Once you are there<sup>1</sup> then you look for a little link labeled [[Index](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/doc-index.html)] beneath the module listing (`GHC.Base` has a huge module listing so in this case it's easier to miss).

Clicking that link takes you to an index of *all the public symbols in that package*; you can click the `>` character to find all operators beginning with a greater than sign. You will then have three links of modules which export that function; click on one and Ctrl-F to find the following documentation:

```
(>>=) :: forall a b. m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b  | infixl 1 | Source
    Sequentially compose two actions, passing any value produced by the first 
    as an argument to the second.
```

Again, [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) does all of this rigamarole for you and has some other nifty features like searching-by-type-signature.

For things like `<-`, `->`, and `=>` which are **not** functions, you will just have to know the language. The meaning of `<-` ("from") is from "do-notation", which you can Google; the meaning of `->` ("to") varies depending on whether it appears in lambda-notation (like `\a b -> b`), case-expressions, or the type signature of a function (where `a -> b -> c` means "a function which takes an `a` and returns a function which takes a `b` and returns some `c`". The meaning of `=>` is from "constraints" or "type classes" in Haskell.

Other than `->`, you can sometimes see operators appearing in type signatures, too. These should be searchable by the above procedure.

1. This is assuming a stable API for the package. If the API has changed you will need to look up with `ghc -v` which package version the file is using, then click on that version.

Comment: You can also skip the GHCi step of finding the package, by just going directly to [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28%3E%3E%3D%29) or [hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%28%3E%3E%3D%29) and searching for the operator (enclose it in parentheses).

Comment: @mhwombat I mentioned hoogle twice, though hayoo is also a good link that deserves to be mentioned here.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature!

Comment: For the more general case of symbolic searches, Symbolhound (http://symbolhound.com/) can help.